# how to force alignment of text with itemize

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize

I have two similar looking sentences and I would like to "push" certain pieces of text to the same x coordinate.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Given $p = 4k+1$ find $(a,b)$ such that $p = a^2 + b^2$ 
    \item Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ find $(x,y,z)$ such that $n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I would like to move the words "find" and "such that" to specific x-coordinates on both sentences so the two sentences align.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tabto` package can help.  Just make sure the tabbing location is rightward of the current location.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, tabto}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Given $p = 4k+1$ \tabto{3.4cm}find $(a,b)$ \tabto{6cm}such that $p = a^2 + b^2$ 
    \item Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ \tabto{3.4cm}find $(x,y,z)$ \tabto{6cm}such that $n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted to use the natural spacing of the text for the tabs, then the following approach would work.  It uses `\savetab{ID}` in the first `\item`, and `\usetab{ID}` in the remaining `\item`s to set and recall tabs.  It also needs `\wideas{wide-text}{narrow-text}` (to be used as needed only in the first `\item`) in case the widest instance of the text is not in the first item.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, tabto}
\def\savetab#1{\tabto*{0cm}\expandafter\edef\csname tab#1\endcsname{\TabPrevPos}%
  \tabto{\TabPrevPos}}
\def\usetab#1{\tabto{\csname tab#1\endcsname}\ignorespaces}
\def\wideas#1#2{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\makebox[\wd0][l]{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Given $p = 4k+1$ \savetab{A} find \wideas{$(x,y,z)$}{$(a,b)$} 
  \savetab{B} such that $p = a^2 + b^2$ 
\item Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ \usetab{A} find $(x,y,z)$ 
  \usetab{B} such that $n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `makebox` to create a box of the appropriate width to obtain the desired alignment:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\AsWideAs}[3][l]{%
    % #1 = alignment: l, r, c
    % #2 = content whose width this is supposed to match
    % #3 = content to be output
    \makebox[\widthof{#2}][#1]{#3}%
}%
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Given $p = 4k+1$  find \AsWideAs{$(x,y,z)$}{$(a,b)$} such that $p = a^2 + b^2$ 
    \item Given \AsWideAs{$p = 4k+1$}{$n \in \mathbb{N}$} find $(x,y,z)$ such that $n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```